# Swap i3 windows changing split structure

Tags: i3

Say you have three windows open in i3 window manager, something like:

```
 1 |
---| 2
 3 |
```

with `1` in focus. What command(s) take you from there to:

```
   1
-------
 3 | 2
```

That is, a sort of merge, or restructuring of the split by changing it from horizontal to vertical, and swapping window `2` for `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the standard keybindings that can be done by pressing `$mod+Shift+Up`.

Comment: Depending on the the exact nesting (internal structure vs. visible structure),  the setting `workspace_layout` and possibly `default_orientation`, you may have to call `move up` (the command behind `$mod+Shift+Up`) repeatedly.